# Which language should I do the coding in to control motion through voice?

Tags: java, voice-recognition, motion

I have to work on a project for my under graduate final year. I have planned to design a system that will control the motion of a wheelchair through voice commands. 
I am basically aiming at using natural voice commands like "move forward", etc to relieve the occupant from precise motion control of the wheelchair.

I have only this idea till now and not a clue about how to go about it.
Please help me with your thoughts on this. And do tell me which language I should use for coding, etc. I am pretty comfortable with java than any other language. Is this achievable through java or should I learn something better?

Comment: If this research involves human subjects, your university's [institutional review board](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institutional_review_board) may be able to offer some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, any language will do. If you are programming on very limited hardware or response time is critical, Java memory consumption and unpredictable GC might be an issue. However Java was designed to work on limited hardware (including [Smart cards](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javacard/overview/index.html)) and carefully designed program should not have problems with GC.

Of course languages closer to the metal, like C, are superior in this case. But if you are comfortable with Java, it will most likely be enough.